# Prototype JS 'getHeight()' changing object visibility and other madness

Tags: javascript, debugging, prototypejs

I am using JS (Prototype & Scriptaculous) to dynamically set the height of a div after an element is added inside the div. My code has been paraphrased below:

```
    bheight = $('body_'+current_item).getHeight();
    bheight += 22;
    bheight += 'px';
    $('body_'+current_item).setStyle({
    height: bheight
    });
```

In the code above, I first use the 'getHeight()' function to get the height of the unique body div. Then I add 22 to that number, and append 'px' to the end, and apply the change using 'setStyle'.

Here comes the weird part. When I run my function that this resides in after page load, everything runs perfectly. If, however, I add a line to run the function at the end of the javascript file (so it is run as the page loads), I get madness. The entire div disappears as the visibility has been magically changed. See a snippet below for info.

```
<div id="body_1" class="edit_bg_box" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: block; width: 200px; height: 22px;">Internal div data...</div>
```

Nowhere in my CSS or code am I setting the visibility to hidden or position to absolute. To compare, below is a snippet of what the div **should** look like.

```
<div id="body_1" class="edit_bg_box"></div>
```

At this point I'm losing my sanity. If I remove the 'getHeight()' function from the main div, everything displays normally (except for the div height which 'getHeight()' was supposed to fix). If I add the 'getheight()' function, the div disappears completely.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot make comments yet so have to post an answer. There's nothing wrong with the part of code you've posted. I guess what's causing the problem has to be from elsewhere, so it'd be great if you could post more code. P.S. You have two divs with one enclosing tag where you say how it should look like. That sure will cause some style problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I fixed the divs issue in my quoted code above, I mistakenly put it in. I have tested the code with and without the 'getWidth()' function, and it works perfectly when the first line of code above is commented out (save for the styling). I can't see how any other code could cause this issue, as it works when the width function is commented out.

Comment: Well I use a div with id="body_1", add an onclick to it and put the same code in the function it was referring to. It works just fine and increases the height on every click. I just added var current_item = 1; above.
How do you initialize current_item? Do you get any errors when debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getHeight()` method makes use of the `getDimensions()` method http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/getDimensions/

and as part of the caveats in the documentation it mentions

> If the element is hidden via `display: none` in CSS, this method will attempt to measure the element by temporarily removing that CSS and applying `visibility: hidden` and `position: absolute`. This gives the element dimensions without making it visible or affecting the positioning of surrounding elements

So there is a possibility that one or more of the parent elements of your div is hidden with `display:none;` and is shown after the page loads.

Comment: This was it! It was a simple bug that I couldn't find until I read your answer. Thank you very much!